# A cellphone emulator

Tags: ubuntu, mobile, emulation

I want to run a cellphone emulator on Ubuntu. I am not picky about any particular cellphone as I am not using it for mobile development instead just to run a small software to generate keys for my personal purpose; as the software is not compatible for ubuntu but is present for cellphones.

Do let me know a suitable emulator source. A high end nokia/Iphone/etc.. phone should be good.

Comment: I think you might need to be a little picky if you're trying to run a particular app - Nokia and iPhone run completely different software. What are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to code in java if you are not picky about the cell phone.

http://www.forum.nokia.com/ you can download a nokia emulator from the code section there, a quick google will show you where to get others - microsoft is built into visual studio when you create a windows mobile project. Not sure about the java apps though.

did a bit more digging and you could also use the [android ADT/device emulator](http://developer.android.com/index.html), although - im not sure you can install the apps on it.  cant you run a mobile phone emulator through WINE in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Nokia emulators only run in Windows.